# changing some values according to a logical index in a specified region of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix and I am interested in changing values that satisfy a certain condition inside that matrix differently, depending on where they are. Say I have a matrix smallPic. How do I obtain a matrix smallPicB with the same dimensions that changed all values that are above 50 in the first two columns to a 255, while those that are in the third and fourth column are changed to a 180?

I have this code which works, but it is pretty ugly and requires splitting the matrix and concatenating it again:

```
smallPic1=smallPic(:,1:2);smallPic1(smalllPic1>50)=255;
smallPic2=smallPic(:,3:4);smallPic2(smalllPic2>50)=180;

smallPicB = [smalllPic1 smalllPic2];
```

How would you combine the logical index with the scalar index in one command?

What doesn't work is this:

```
smallPic(:,smallPic(:,3:4)>50) = 180
```

Here, the second mention of smallPic inside the brackets does not allow indexing into the correct position of smallPic because it doesn't have the same dimensions as smallPic. So this command actually replaces values in the first two columns of smallPic that are in the same row as those values that are above 50 in the third and fourth column, instead of replacing the values in the third and fourth column themselves.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: about your edit: That's why I defined J, which stores column index of all members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably is not what you're looking for, but it can help if you have lots of assignments like that:

```
J = repmat(1:size(smallPic, 2), size(smallPic, 1), 1)
smallPic((J<3)&(smallPic>50))=255
smallPic((J>2)&(J<5)&(smallPic>50))=180
```

You can also call [`ismember`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwinrb_khvnNAhWCbRQKHeUgCpwQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathworks.com%2Fhelp%2Fmatlab%2Fref%2Fismember.html&usg=AFQjCNEMg9OE8mDUs0v0WSqUlLvwckaTNw&sig2=qi66XfAlfFgJnXE75dlDAQ&bvm=bv.127178174,d.bGs) function if column indices are not consecutive:

```
smallPic(ismember(J, [[1:2 5:6]])&(smallPic>50))=255
```